# Beaglebone Black Rev C PRU Shared Memory

Tags: memory-management, shared-memory, beagleboneblack

Currently working with the Beaglebone Black Rev C and the PRU has the following arrangement:

[image: PRU layout]

I have successfully been able to have one PRU access its own 8K, the other PRU's 8K, and the shared 12K.

This leaves me with a total memory of 28K. Storing float's I can store 7,168 values. I would like to capture 20,000 values in about 250ms.

The Derek Malloy tutorial on PRU's (http://exploringbeaglebone.com/chapter15/) claims, "a pool of 2,000,000 bytes is allocated for the sample data". Things appear to have changed since the writing of that tutorial. No more dynamic Device Tree through UIO and PRU's accessed through Remote Proc. Not sure if the architecture changed as well. This makes most of the printed material out of date concerning PRU's and it's painful to figure out what is current and not. I would love to have these 2,000,000 bytes available in the new architecture. Needing help with the addressing, and some code samples would be excellent. Hoping someone out there can help me get it.

Question: Is there a way, technique, or resources that can be applied to allow me to do this? Remember, 20,000 samples in 250ms when providing a response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend asking this from the [beagleboard groups](https://groups.google.com/g/beagleboard) where the matter experts lurk.

Comment: That is 320,000 Bytes/s. Should not be too much. You have to move the data to main memory during the akquisition. There can be unpredictable latency. Are both PRUs occupied? Otherwise one can read the samples, the other write the data away. The shared data can be used as a cache.